# Visual Studio: Can I have a "Manage Bower Packages" in a node js console app?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, bower

Working on Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 - I created a new Node.js console app.

I have a NPM where I can add packages. One of the packages I can add is bower. But I don't understand how I now manage/add packages through bower. 
[image]
I don't have anything set up as a path environment variable, so I can't really use the `npm install -g bower` ... Nor do I want to - rather use the IDE...

Is it possible? (I know in [some](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower) applications you do get a manager)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like visual studio requires a bower.json "bower configuration file" in your project in order to enable the "manage bower packages" menu.

Add bower as a dev dependency in your package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bower": "1.8.4"
}
```

In Task Runner Explorer (View -> Other Windows -> Task Runner Explorer)
Run the install task under package.json Defaults

All that being said, bower is deprecated.

https://bower.io/blog/

Ideally for such a project you would be using either npm or yarn for node package management.  Especially since Bower's purpose was for managing front-end javascript dependencies.

You can install npm packages without using the command line by editing the package.json file.  Simply add a package to the correct dependency section (devDependencies or dependencies) then run npm install from Task Runner Explorer